# Checkbox onchange show div and cheked another checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

How can I modify this code. Can I use one evenlistner there to implement the same result. What is the best practice in this case. Can I use here data atribute, or querySelector better. [codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/rWQWMq?editors=1010)

```js
     const myCheck = document.getElementById("check");
     const myCheck2 = document.getElementById("check2");
     const dib = document.getElementById("dib");
     function change() {
     if (myCheck2.checked) {
      myCheck.checked = false;
      dib.style.display = "block";
     }
     else{
      dib.style.display = "none";
      myCheck.checked = true;
     }
    }
    function func2() {
     if (this.checked) {
      myCheck2.checked = false;
      dib.style.display = "none";
    }
     else {
      dib.style.display = "block";
      myCheck2.checked = true;
     }
    }

    myCheck2.addEventListener('click', change);
    myCheck.addEventListener('click', func2);
```

```html
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" >
     <input type="checkbox" id="check2" checked="checked" >
     <div id="dib">Text</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? A little bit of background would be very helpful.

Comment: You are doing OK, although I don't know what you are trying to archive.
Just a suggestion that you should use "change" event, instead of "click": 

`myCheck2.addEventListener('change', change); myCheck.addEventListener('change', func2);`

Comment: @vothaison - I recommend the click event for checkboxes, because certain browsers don't trigger the change event on checkboxes until they lose focus. (Noting that a click event will be triggered even if the user changes the checkbox via the keyboard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two improvements you could make to your existing code without changing the logic at all would be to use meaningful names for your functions, and to fix the indenting. But anyway...

If I've understood your existing code, the idea is that when either checkbox is checked the other should be automatically unchecked (in which case why not use radio buttons?), and the associated div should be displayed only if the second checkbox is checked? If so, you could combine the code into a single function as follows:

```js
const myCheck = document.getElementById("check");
const myCheck2 = document.getElementById("check2");
const dib = document.getElementById("dib");

function cbChanged() {
   (this === myCheck ? myCheck2 : myCheck).checked = !this.checked;
   
   dib.style.display = myCheck2.checked ? "block" : "none";
}

myCheck2.addEventListener('click', cbChanged);
myCheck.addEventListener('click', cbChanged);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" >
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" checked="checked">
<div id="dib">Text</div>
```

Notice that the above still binds two event listeners, but to the same function.

Below is a more generic version that uses a container around the checkboxes and their associated div so that you could have multiple copies of that on the page all handled by one event listener wired up with a similar amount of JS to the previous version:

```js
function cbChanged(e) {
  const showCB = this.querySelector(".show");
  const hideCB = this.querySelector(".hide");

  (e.target === hideCB ? showCB : hideCB).checked = !e.target.checked;
   
  this.querySelector("div").style.display = showCB.checked ? "block" : "none";
}

const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(containers, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', cbChanged);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide" >
  <input type="checkbox" class="show" checked="checked">
  <div>Text One</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide" >
  <input type="checkbox" class="show" checked="checked">
  <div>Text Two</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide" >
  <input type="checkbox" class="show" checked="checked">
  <div>Text Three</div>
</div>
```